How to Use proxy org.apache.sshd.client SFTP
Has anyone already coded the way to go through the proxy with the Java library Apache.SSHD?
I'm using this version:  sshd-core, version 2.12.1
From my analysis, it uses this method (setClientProxyConnector).   Example doesn't work ... (see method sendClientProxyMetadata):
This is my code :
package com.sftp;
import com.reservit.sftp.exception.SendingSystemException;
import org.apache.sshd.client.SshClient;
import org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientProxyConnector;
import org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientSession;
import org.apache.sshd.sftp.client.SftpClient;
import org.apache.sshd.sftp.client.SftpClientFactory;
public class SshSftpBO2 {
  private SshSftpBO2() {} /**      * @param tmpFile  fichier temporraire cree, ex /home/xxx/ExportXXX.csv      * @param fileName nom du fichier, ex ExportXXX.csv      */
  public void uploadFile(String tmpFile, String fileName) throws SendingSystemException {
      try {
        String host = "sftp.com";
        int port = 22;
        String username = "login";
        String password = "pass";
        String remoteDirectory = "/";
        byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(tmpFile));
        try (SshClient client = SshClient.setUpDefaultClient()) {
          client.start();
          try (ClientSession session = client.connect(username, host, port).verify().getSession()) {
            session.addPasswordIdentity(password);
            session.auth().verify();
            client.setClientProxyConnector(new ClientProxyConnector() {
                  @Override public void sendClientProxyMetadata(ClientSession clientSession) throws Exception { // "Unable to find the right lines of code for this... ... ???"                         }                     });                      try (SftpClient sftpClient = SftpClientFactory.instance().createSftpClient(session)) {                         try (OutputStream outputStream = sftpClient.write(remoteDirectory + "/" + fileName)) {                             outputStream.write(bytes);                         }                     }                 }             }         } catch (Exception e) {             System.err.println("Error");         }     } }

Thank you for your examples.

What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What happens when you run your code, and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See also [ask].
